# ASP.net Templated User Control

Tags: user-controls

I have seen some templated user controls like:

```
<uc:Control1 ID="Uc1" runat="server">
    <messagetemplate>a</messagetemplate>
</uc:Control1>
```

So far so good. But what I want to do is pass parameters to the control like.

```
<uc:Control1 ID="Uc1" runat="server">
    <messagetemplate>
        <CustomAttribute="Color" Value="Green" />
        <CustomAttribute="Size" Value="Small" />
        <CustomAttribute="Param1" Value="1" />
    </messagetemplate>
</uc:Control1>
```

Could you please show me a way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [short tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx) on the MSDN website. Maybe it helps you a little bit?